# Building MySQL searching query using LIKE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

I make a PHP MySQL search, the custom may be type something like `word` or `word1 word2` or `word1 word2 word3`... I need to get the final query like

```
$qry = "SELECT title,content,date 
FROM articles WHERE 
(title like '%$word1%' and title '%$word2%') 
OR 
(content like '%$word1%' and content title '%$word2%')"
OR
(title like '%$word1%' and content title '%$word2%')
OR
(title like '%$word2%' and content title '%$word1%'); // make sure custom type words all match in database column title and content, maybe only '%$word1%', or maybe multi words '%$word1%', '%$word2%', '%$word3%'...
```

I use some code below, but it could not reach my request. how to make it right? Thanks.

```
$qry = "SELECT title,content,date FROM articles";
if($_REQUEST['search']!=""){
    $searchText = $_REQUEST['search'];
    $words = preg_split("/\s+/",$searchText); 
    $uniqueWords = array_keys(array_flip($words)); 
    $parts = '';
    foreach($uniqueWords as $word){     
    $parts[] = " content like '%$word%' ";
    } 
    $where = implode(" AND ", $parts);
    foreach($uniqueWords as $word){     
    $parts[] = " title like '%$word%' ";
    } 
    $where1 = implode(" AND ", $parts);
    foreach($uniqueWords as $word){     
    $parts[] = " title like '%$word%' OR content like '%$word%' ";
    } 
    $where2 = implode(" AND ", $parts);
    $qry .=" WHERE $where OR $where1 OR $where2 Order By date DESC ";
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using MySQL full text searching? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Full-text Search - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html - may be along the lines of what you need.

Comment: @Lucanos there is a nice echo in here! :-)

Comment: @Treffynnon: Great minds thing alike. Your comment only appeared after I left mine. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after (are you wanting to match any keyword in title or contents or match both keywords to both columns...?) But what about something like this:

```
$keywords = explode(' ',mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search']));
$qry = "SELECT title,content,date FROM articles WHERE (";
$qry2 = '';
foreach($keywords as $n => $word)
{
    $qry2 .= " title LIKE '%$word%' OR content LIKE '%$word%' OR";
}
$qry .= trim($qry2, 'OR');
$qry .= ") ORDER BY title";
```

Not tested this, but it seems ok.